# How to store global data in QList

Tags: qt, qlist

Can you explain a methods for storing program data with global access ?

I found these keywords:
- using static class to store data
- pass QList by value
- pass Qlist by reference
- use 'friend' keyword

but I cannot find any real example of storing global QList, as they say, it is a bad design to use global variables. Also there is a mention that using pointers on a QList is a bad idea because of implicit sharing (?).

So where should I store my Qlist for accessing it from a different class in an other .cpp ? So I have:

mainwindow.h

```
QList <SceneCard> sceneList;
QString mTitle;

public slots:
QString setValue()
    {
       return mTitle;
    }
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::AddScene()
{
    sceneCard = new SceneCard(sNumber);
    sceneList.append(sceneCard);
    mTitle = "Nejat is right!"

}

void MainWindow::showSceneCard()
{
    SceneDialog D;
    connect(D,SIGNAL(getValue()),this,SLOT(setValue()));
    D.exec();
}
```

scenedialog.h

```
#ifndef SCENEDIALOG_H
#define SCENEDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QList>

namespace Ui {
class SceneDialog;
}

class SceneDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SceneDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~SceneDialog();

signals:
    QString getValue();

private:
    Ui::SceneDialog *ui;
    QString myText;
};
```

scenedialog.cpp

```
#include "scenedialog.h"
#include "ui_scenedialog.h"
#include <QDebug>

SceneDialog::SceneDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SceneDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    myText = getValue();
    qDebug() << myText; // myText is empty!!

}
```

Comment: You should be familiar with the singleton conecpt. Create a singleton class that contains a QList member. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern for more information about this pattern.

Comment: What do you mean by "store"? Having a member function who return the list does make the deal? Sending a signal with the list doesnt either?

Comment: 'Store' means that I need to read/write this QList from different .cpp files. List should be accessible globally.

Comment: Ok, maybe I should re-phrase: I have visual nodes in mainwindow, and call dialog for editing their properties. Then I should pass properties of all nodes  to an other QWidgetTab

Comment: So pass the needed data to your dialog, and when dialog is closed by accepting it, get the new data from the dialog. I don't see why you would need a global `QList` for this.

Comment: But I need to store data somewhere before passing it into a dialog ?

Comment: Keep it in a member variable somewhere. Where do you create the data in the first place?

Comment: @thuga In mainwindow, see the edit

Comment: Well there you go, you're already storing the data somewhere. Now just create a function in your `SceneDialog` that takes a `QList<SceneCard*>` as a parameter, and pass `sceneList` to it. By the way, it seems it should be  `QList<SceneCard*>` in your `mainwindow.h`.

Comment: @thuga I bow to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your list as a class member and use Qt's Signal/slot mechanism to access the list from other classes. Just make a signal in the target class, connect it to a slot in the class containing the list and make a connection between two objects of the classes. This way you can access any data member of other classes by connecting a signal to a slot returning that value and just emitting the signal and getting the return value.

For example if you have two classes like :

```
class A: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    A(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~A();

signals:
      int getValue();

private:

      void someFunction()
      {
           int val = getValue();
      }
};

class B 
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    B(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~B();

public slots:

      int getValue()
      {
           return someValue;
      }
};
```

And connect the signal from an object of `A` to the slot in an object of `B` :

```
connect(a, SIGNAL(getValue()), b, SLOT(getValue()));
```

In class `A` you can access the value returned from `getValue` slot in `B` by just calling the signal and using the returned value.

Note that the two objects should be in the same thread for this to work. If they are in different threads then the connection type should be of type `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` :

```
connect(a, SIGNAL(getValue()), b, SLOT(getValue()), Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
```

Another way is two use static class members but it is not recommended unless you have a good reason to do it. If you have two classes like :

```
class A {
   public:
      static QList<int> list;
};

class B {
   public:
      void do_something();
};
```

You can access A's static data member from B like this:

```
void B::do_something()
{
     int val = A::list[0];
     ...
};
```

Comment: Ugh.. thanks! So its just: 'class myList : public QList {}' ?

Comment: @DensiTensy You probably don't want to subclass `QList`.

Comment: @DensiTensy How did you conclude from the answer that you should subclass QList ?!

Comment: @Nejat I'm noob! So i've mistaken 'class member' for subclassing. So _list_ in class A is a class member ?

Comment: Yes. It is a static class member which could be access globally by prefixing the class name.

Comment: @Nejat, can you be so kind to post an example of a connection between classes ? I read docs, it says nothing about slot's return values.

Comment: @Nejat I followed your instruction, but myText is not effected. Whats wrong, it should be mTitle now ?

Comment: Is it because I connect after constructing my Dialog ? If so, how a Dialog should be getting values, if not in his constructor ?

Comment: Yeah. First the constructor is called before you connect. You can emit the signal `getValue()` in the `showEvent` of the dialog. Also you should use the address of the dialog when connecting : `connect(&D,SIGNAL(getValue()),this,SLOT(setValue()))`;